# Exporting and importing Kickoff Application Launcher's menu?

Tags: 14.04, kubuntu, kickoff

Is there any way to export and import Kickoff Application Launcher's menu (i.e. the application list)? I use Kubuntu 14.10 LTS x64.

Comment: You mean kickoff settings, such as modern, hotkey, etc, or do you mean the application list (tree-structure, custom applications, etc)?

Comment: @MarcosRorizJunior  application list

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.